# Intercept Deletes in ASP.NET WebAPI - Breeze

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, breeze

I'm using BreezeJS for connecting to an OData endpoint, developed using ASP.NET. I use the EFContextProvider for saving changes.

This all works great, but now I want to not delete data, but set a Deleted field to true. How can I intercept Deletes?

Thanks!

Regards,
Matthijs ter Woord

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use the [BeforeSaveEntities](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/efcontextprovider-methods) interceptor on your EFContextProvider instance to change the `EntityState` to "Modified" and set the Deleted flag on your entity.  For example:

```
protected override Dictionary<Type, List<EntityInfo>> BeforeSaveEntities(Dictionary<Type, List<EntityInfo>> saveMap) 
{
    var orderInfos = saveMap[typeof(Order)];
    foreach (var info in orderInfos) 
    {
        var order = (Order)info.Entity;
        if (info.EntityState == EntityState.Deleted) 
        {
            order.Deleted = true;
            info.EntityState = EntityState.Modified;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Will the client know that order was not deleted, but instead modified?

Comment: I have NuGet package Breeze.WebApi 1.4.0 installed, and EntityState property is readonly. I already tried this.. :(

Comment: I'm developing a SaaS solution, where we (service provider) want to keep the data around for doing analysis. The tenants wont see their data back again. (So, it's still a functional delete)

Answer (score 0):

Once you mark an entity for deletion, you still have to call SaveChanges to persist it and will be able to intercept the save call regardless of if you are modifying, deleting, or creating new entities.

The save call interception is done in the BeforeSaveEntity and/or BeforeSaveEntities. (See http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/efcontextprovider)

Comment: I have NuGet package Breeze.WebApi 1.4.0 installed, and EntityState property is readonly. I already tried this.. :(

Comment: You shouldn't try to change the EntityState directly, but rather use the setDeleted()/setModified() methods of EntityAspect. More info at http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityAspect.html.

Comment: sbelini: setDeleted/setModified is in BreezeJS on the client, I'm talking about server-side.

Answer (score 0):

The `EntityInfo.EntityState` is not set-able by your code ... exactly as you observed. I'm not sure why we decided to block that option but let's take it as a given. Here's something to try.

You can remove an `EntityInfo` from the `saveMap` passed into `BeforeSaveEntities` (its a `Dictionary<Type, List<EntityInfo>>`); that should keep Breeze from trying to save the delete-entity request.

Now **add a new `EntityInfo`** to the dictionary, this time with the `EntityState` of the `EntityInfo` in modified state. The following three lines should do the trick:

```
var newInfo = context.CreateEntityInfo(revisedEntity, EntityState.Modified);
newInfo.OriginalValuesMap['Deleted']=true;  // so Context persists change to this property
saveMap[revisedEntity.getType()].add(newInfo);
```

I have not tried this; I'm writing the code right here in SO so it probably won't even compile. But you get the idea.

**Warning** There is a some chance that the `ContextProvider` will send this entity back to the Breeze client as if it had been truly Modified; this may confuse breeze which might keep it in cache in an Unmodified state, just as it would after saving a modified entity. Please test for this. If that's what happens, you can put some extra logic in the save success callback to remove this entity from cache (putting it in the Detached state).

### Update 8/5/2013

I accept your challenge. Please explain why the following code works in my debugger when I set a breakpoint on the first line of my `BeforeSaveEntities` method :-)

```
saveMap[typeof(Zza.Model.Customer)][0].OriginalValuesMap; // Count = 0
saveMap[typeof(Zza.Model.Customer)][0].OriginalValuesMap["Deleted"] = true; 
saveMap[typeof(Zza.Model.Customer)][0].OriginalValuesMap["Deleted"]; // true
saveMap[typeof(Zza.Model.Customer)][0].OriginalValuesMap.Count; // 1
```

Comment: Hello Ward, Thanks for the info! Except that OriginalValuesMap is null, and readonly..